# SSH dns issue giving break-in error

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

Address *.*.*.* maps to ec2-*-*-*-*.compute-1.amazonaws.com, but this does not map back to the address - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!

I keep getting this when I try to log-in to my remote server.  I have it set for key authentication and when this error comes through, I still have to push through the password.  I want to use this for automated Git pulls, and I can't have this kind of error message.  anybody know what is going on here and how to fix it?

Comment: Give us the real error message so we can verify the situation for ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

Set CheckHostIp to no may work in your ssh conf, depending on your version.